# Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token in jshint

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jslint, ecmascript-5, jshint

I am working with Eclipse and installed jshint for my application development with node.js, and now I am working on socket.io, where I have written following code.

```
io.sockets.in('room').emit('event_name', data);
```

here I am getting warrning from jshint as follows in Eclipse (Kepler).

```
Syntax error on token ".", Identifier expected after this token
```

How Do I solve this problem? Can someone tell me what the syntax error is here?

Comment: Holy crap, [`io.sockets.in`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms#emitting-to-a-room) is a real thing. It looks like a syntax error. I don't know why it's not a syntax error; apparently JSHint doesn't know either. I'm not sure you'll be able to silence this warning without somehow hiding this line from JSHint entirely; JSHint can't parse your file with this line in it.

Comment: [Apparently Javascript has separate Identifier and IdentifierName productions, and only Identifiers are required to not be reserved words.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#Reserved_word_usage) It looks like JSHint isn't aware of this.

Comment: This is probably issue of the JSHint version... *IdentifierNames* are supported as defined in the specification (https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/309).

Comment: JSLint.com is happy with that line, if you put in a `var io, data;` declaration first. Looks like you've [asked this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337466/jshint-throwing-error-regarding-identifier-expected-after-token), btw, but added the JSLint tag. Kinda a blatant dupe. ;) Is JSLint an option?

Comment: @ruffin, this is just an example, in my original code I have written/declared all needed variables as you mentioned. still I have got this error. I have asked this question 2nd time with Jshint tag, because I forgot that. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think since you're using JSHint (and using via a plugin on Eclipse), this isn't technically a JSLint question. That said, I'm suspicious if you gave the code in more context (ie, list more of the code), it'd be easier to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSHint docs: http://www.jshint.com/docs/

```
ignoreThis(); // jshint ignore:line
```

That should work. There may also be some other configuration to ignore certain errors. Obviously you wouldn't want to ignore all syntax errors...

Comment: It's disappear for a while, but when I ran "Build Project" then again it error/warning comes.